# Change custom text field background color and text color IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

I'm using following custom text field class to change appearance of the text field. Now I need to change text field's background color, text color and place holder color, when user start editing and end editing the text field. How to do it, using this class.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField{

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        //Border
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        //Background
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)

        //Text
        self.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add self as a target for the UIControl events you need according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:)

There you have control events for EditingDidBegin and such.

Something like this:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: "myFunc", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin);
```

Comment: This method is helping me to do what I wanted to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

In your `CustomTextField` class you can add a property observer:

```
var change: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        textColor = change ? .yellow : .black
        backgroundColor = change ? .blue : .white
    }
}
```

and in your ViewController:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    customTextField.change = true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    customTextField.change = false
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate of your textfield, in storyboard or programmatically.

EDIT:
Shortened the code and updated for Swift 3

Comment: Missing a dot before white on backgroundColor line.
It should be:
backgroundColor = change ? .blue : .white

Answer (score 1):

Select the text field -> click "identity inspector" icon -> click on Plus button "user Defined runtime attributes" -> add this text "_placeholderLabel.textColor" in "key path" field -> choose the "Type" "color" and set the value color.[image: Please check the images in detail]

Answer (score 0):

@objc func myfunc( _ textfield : UITextField) {

```
    textfield.backgroundColor = Helper.UIColorFromRGB(0xFFF1F3)
    
}
@objc func myfunc1( _ textfield : UITextField) {
    
    textfield.layer.borderColor = Helper.UIColorFromRGB(0xFF4D67) as! CGColor
    
    textfield.backgroundColor = Helper.UIColorFromRGB(0xFAFAFA)
}


func textfieldBackgroundColor( _ textfield : UITextField) {
    
    textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myfunc), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)
    textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myfunc1), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEnd)

    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer's code is deprecated.

Old Code:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(func), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
```

'UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin'
changed to
'UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin'

New Code:

```
nameTF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(func), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidBegin)
nameTF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(func), for: UIControl.Event.editingDidEnd)
```