# Custom textfield doesn't change default appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a few textfields in my view controller, I created a custom class for them:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.textColor = UIColor.white
}
}
```

In my view controller, the outlets are created like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemCountTextField: CustomTextField! { didSet { itemCountTextField.delegate = self } }
```

But when I ran it, the UITextFields still look like default white text fields, the customization isn't done, where did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you need set border style to other kind to get out of the default style also

Comment: @Tj3n I just tried, doesn't seem the case, plus it seems to work well in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888253/change-custom-text-field-background-color-and-text-color-ios-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the UITextField subclass is `CustomTextField` & then works...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the textfield class to `CustomTextField` also in your Storyboard/Xib, just changing the outlet type is not enough.